# Paypal integration to android app - Receiver

Tags: android, paypal, integration

I'm trying to integrate Paypal to my android app.I've watched tutorial about this but I didn't understand one thing. How we can add the paypal account of Receiver. User is buying something and paying for this yes, but where is going the money ? (I want to add my paypal account and when the user pay, the money goes to my paypal account)

Answer (score 0):

The concept here is,

During the PayPal integration, you need to authenticate yourself by using authenticate API. As a result of that API call, you will receive one token from PayPal.  You need to pass that token as a part of every payment call. So if the buyer paid by using your payment API, then PayPal will identify your receiver account by your token and credit amount in your account once the payment got completed.